# Golang JSON weird behaviour

Tags: mysql, json, go

Fairly unremarkable code here:

```
type Response struct {
    Status    string      `json:"status"`
    Msg       string      `json:"msg"`
    ErrorCode string      `json:"error-code"`
    Data      interface{} `json:"data"`
    Eof       bool        `json:"eof"`
}

func main() {
    data := [][]string{
        []string{"description", "BILL NO 2362 EXTRA 5%"},
    }

    r := &Response{
        Data: data,
    }

    str, _ := json.Marshal(r)
    fmt.Println(string(str))
}
```

It prints the following:

```
{"status":"","msg":"","error-code":"","data":[["description","BILL NO 2362 EXTRA 5%"]],"eof":false}
```

No problem so far. However if I try to marshal JSON from exactly the same data, but fetched from a DB, I get a weird output:

```
func TestJson(t *testing.T) {
    var pool *sql.DB
    pool, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:pass@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/db")
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    defer pool.Close()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    if err := pool.PingContext(ctx); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    data := fetchAll(t, ctx, pool)
    fmt.Println(data)

    res := &Response{
        Data: data,
    }

    str, err := json.Marshal(res)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Printf(string(str))
}


func fetchAll(t *testing.T, ctx context.Context, pool *sql.DB) [][]string {
    rows, err := pool.QueryContext(ctx, "select description from vouchers where id = 1")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    cols, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    vals := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
    var results [][]string

    for rows.Next() {
        for i := range cols {
            vals[i] = &vals[i]
        }

        err = rows.Scan(vals...)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("%s\n", err.Error())
        }

        var r []string
        for i, c := range cols {
            r = append(r, c)
            var v string

            if vals[i] == nil {
                v = "NULL"
            } else {
                b, _ := vals[i].([]byte)
                v = string(b)
            }

            fmt.Printf("byte len %d\n", len(v))
            fmt.Printf("rune len %d\n", utf8.RuneCountInString(v))

            r = append(r, v)
        }

        results = append(results, r)
    }

    if rows.Err() != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    return results
}
```

The test code prints this:

```
=== RUN   TestJson
byte len 21
rune len 21
[[description BILL NO 2362 EXTRA 5%]]
{"status":"","msg":"","error-code":"","data":[["description","BILL NO 2362 EXTRA 5%!"(MISSING)]],"eof":false}--- PASS: TestJson (0.35s)
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  0.836s
```

Note the corrupted JSON. I printed the rune length of the string to make sure the string contains
just plain ascii characters. The print before the marshal confirms that we are looking at exactly the same string. Why on earth is the output different ?

If I remove the last "%" then life returns to normal:

```
byte len 20
rune len 20
[[description BILL NO 2362 EXTRA 5]]
{"status":"","msg":"","error-code":"","data":[["description","BILL NO 2362 EXTRA 5"]],"eof":false}--- PASS: TestJson (0.35s)
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  0.534s
```

Comment: The application uses the data as the format argument to fmt.Printf..  Use `fmt.Printf("%s", str)` or `fmt.Print(string(str))` instead of  `fmt.Printf(string(str))`.

Comment: Indeed, the issue is you're using `Printf` when you shouldn't be. `Printf` sees the `%` as a format string, but you're not actually trying to do formatting, so you should just be using `Println`.

Comment: Yes, I went through lot of trouble to find a non existent problem ..I never noticed that for the database case I was using Printf unlike Println in the standalone code. Part of learning a new language I guess ..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions modify the program as follows:

```
func TestJson(t *testing.T) {
    var pool *sql.DB
    pool, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:pass@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/db")
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    defer pool.Close()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    if err := pool.PingContext(ctx); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    data := fetchAll(t, ctx, pool)
    fmt.Println(data)

    res := &Response{
        Data: data,
    }

    str, err := json.Marshal(res)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Print(string(str))
}


func fetchAll(t *testing.T, ctx context.Context, pool *sql.DB) [][]string {
    rows, err := pool.QueryContext(ctx, "select description from vouchers where id = 1")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    cols, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    vals := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
    var results [][]string

    for rows.Next() {
        for i := range cols {
            vals[i] = &vals[i]
        }

        err = rows.Scan(vals...)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("%s\n", err.Error())
        }

        var r []string
        for i, c := range cols {
            r = append(r, c)
            var v string

            if vals[i] == nil {
                v = "NULL"
            } else {
                b, _ := vals[i].([]byte)
                v = string(b)
            }

            fmt.Printf("byte len %d\n", len(v))
            fmt.Printf("rune len %d\n", utf8.RuneCountInString(v))

            r = append(r, v)
        }

        results = append(results, r)
    }

    if rows.Err() != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    return results
}
```